# Does Solr store the original contents of the document after indexing?

Tags: security, solr

If I mark a field as "don't store," does Solr retain the original contents of that field anywhere, or does it only retain the "bag of words" that it culls for the index itself?

I'm asking from the standpoint of document security. If someone cracked into the machine running our Solr index, could they get the original text passed into Solr for this "don't store" field, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Solr index does not store the original value in any retrievable or viewable way for fields that are set to `stored="false"`. [Common Field options](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options) on the Solr wiki states the following behavior of setting the stored option.

> True if the value of the field should be retrievable during a search

If someone cracked into the machine running the Solr index and ran Solr queries based on the above they would not be able to see the contents of the field as Solr would not return that field. However if they had access to the disk and the actual index folder and segment files as written by Lucene, they could see the terms that Solr stored for each document in that field using [Luke - Lucene Index Toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to examine the index folder.

Answer (score 3):

When a field is Storable.No, only enough information is stored for Lucene to perform the search.

However, if you specify WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS when constructing each field, there is usually enough information to retrieve:

```
lowercase(EXACTSTRINGINDEXED) - LUCENEDELIMITERS - STOPWORDS
```

For example, if you indexed:

```
Jerry&Mary's Live Bait and Yellow Cab
```

with an analyzer that treats "&" and "'" as delimiters, did not index single letters, and treated 'and' as a stopword, you would see in the index something like:

```
jerry mary live bait [null word] yellow cab
```

*(You can verify this with Luke, as mentioned above.)*